# Piping STDOUT of spawn process into superagent upload

Tags: node.js, spawn, superagent

I'm struggling to work out how to take the output of a spawned child process and feed that output into a multipart mime upload.

Here is what I have that as far as I can tell *should* work

```
var request = require('superagent');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var spawned = spawn('echo', ['hello', 'world']);

request.post('http://localhost/api/upload')
    .attach('file', spawned.stdout)
    .end(function(res) {
        console.log("DONE", res);
    });
```

Unfortunately this throws the rather unhelpful `Error: socket hang up` response from Node.

Answer (score 0):

You're quite close!

Here's the final version which does what you want:

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var request = require('superagent');

exec('echo hello world', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  request.post('http://localhost/api/upload')
    .attach('file', stdout)
    .end(function(res) {
      console.log('DONE', res);
});
```

I'm using `exec` here, because it's callback function outputs the stdout and stderr streams, which it seems like you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

I re-wrote your example a little as Superagent really don't like using buffers instead of Streams. I've replaced it in the below with Request instead: https://gist.github.com/hash-bang/f897f72fa8048ebb315d

This does work as you said. Shame I can't find a means of making this work with Streams instead though.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that :( Sorry ><

Comment: You're method works fine though. Just uses buffers instead of Streams. After much experimentation I still can't find a way of making this work.